# Using remapped Left Control <LCTL> key as shortcut

Tags: ubuntu, x11, gnome, keyboard-layout, xkb

I have remapped the `<LCTL>` key to *Tab* in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/en` using

```
key <LCTL> { [    Tab,   Tab,       Tab,         Tab  ] };
key <MENU> { [ Alt_R,      Alt_R,         Alt_R,            Alt_R ] };
```

I now want to set a shortcut for `Switch applications` to `Alt + Tab` using the remapped left control key as `Tab`. However, two problems arise.

1. The `Keyboard -> Sortcuts` interface in Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 does not recognize my currently active custom keyboard layout, but instead interprets my keystrokes as coming from standard QWERTY. And in QWERTY `Alt + Ctrl` is not enough to make a shortcut.
2. Even after assigning `Switch applications` to `Alt + Tab` (by switching active keyboard layouts), pressing these keys in my custom layout has no effect! Only pressing the corresponding QWERTY keys does.

In short, the `Shortcuts` interface seems to completely ignore my custom layout.

What can I do to make my custom layout also work with shortcuts?

Comment: I think you need to reassign modifiers as well, otherwise parts of the system will still see `LCTL` as a Control modifier key and `MENU` as not an Alt modifier key.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Do you know how I can reassign the Control modifier?

Comment: (only for a specific layout and not universally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading a little bit on assigning modifiers, following the hint from Gilles, I came up with

```
key <TAB>  { [ BackSpace ] };
key <CAPS> { [ Control_L ] };
key <LCTL> { [ Tab ] };
key <MENU> { [ Alt_R ] };

modifier_map Control { <CAPS> };
modifier_map Mod1 { Alt_L, Alt_R, <MENU> };
```

This solves problems 1 and 2. Thanks a lot, Gilles!

(Unfortunately the modifier remappings stick across keyboard layouts, even though I have only configured them for one. But this might be better discussed in a separate question.)